# Stream data using Firebase Realtime Database rest api with nodeMCU client

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, http, stream

I have data on firebase rtdb, which i want to listen in my nodemcu. I know there are libraries available like [this one](https://github.com/mobizt/Firebase-ESP8266) which provides listeners, but i want to do it using REST API streaming as mentioned in [firebase documentation for rest api streaming](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-streaming).
So far i have successfully tested with curl on cmd as shown[image]

My curl command is:

```
curl -v https://<name of rtdb>.firebaseio.com/SD0001/Up.json -H "Accept:text/event-stream"
```

I want to do the same thing on ESP8266 using [ESP8266HTTPClient](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/ESP8266HTTPClient) library. The firebase documentation states "Set the client's Accept header to text/event-stream" (which i added in header), "Respect HTTP Redirects, in particular HTTP status code 307" (which i am still struggling).

So far, my code is somewhat like this

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecureBearSSL.h>

const uint8_t fingerprint[20] = {<<<<fingerprint of rtdb database>>>>};
HTTPClient https;
std::unique_ptr<BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure>client(new BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure);
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin("SSID", "PASSWORD");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP()); // successful Connection of ESP8266,


  client->setFingerprint(fingerprint);

  if (https.begin(*client, "https://<name of rtdb>.firebaseio.com/SD0001/Up.json"))
  {
    https.addHeader("Accept", "text/event-stream", false, true);
    https.setFollowRedirects(HTTPC_FORCE_FOLLOW_REDIRECTS);
    int httpCode = https.GET();
    Serial.println(httpCode);

    Serial.println(https.getString());    
    //    Serial.println(https.getLocation());
    //    Serial.println(https.header("Location"));
    //https.end();
  }

}

void loop()
{
  //  Serial.println(https.getStream());
  //  Serial.println(https.getString());
  //  Serial.println(https.getLocation());
  //  delay(1000);
}
```

My code GETs the respone with 200 code, but there is no "Location" to redirect in the response header (at least i can't find any). Should i do http GET in the loop everytime? If so, where will i get my redirection url?
It would be really helpful if any solution is provided or any documentation to guide me in the right way.

Edit: I have put the text versions of curl command and the code in the post alongwith the screenshots. This is my first post here, so please bear with me.

Comment: please remove the screenshot of the code and replace it with the code text ... do the same with the first screenshot also

Comment: @jsotola i have put the actual code in text form. Please look into it. any help is appreciated as i am completely at sea here